# I have a file which have transaction Id and xml data which is separated by comma(,) .I want to have only the xml file by removing the tranction ID

Tags: pyspark, xml-parsing, databricks

I have a file which has transactionId and xml data in it and which is separated by comma(,) .

I want to have only the xml file by removing the tranction ID and process the xml data; but I am not able to do so in pyspark.

**Method 1 - I followed:**

I tried to read the file as csv then dropped the first column and concatenated rest others columns and writing the file as text format.

```py
df_spike = spark.read.format('csv').option('delimiter',',').load(readLocation)
df_spike = df_spike.drop("\_c0")
columns = df_spike.columns
df_spike = df_spike.withColumn('fresh',concat_ws(",", \*\[col(x) for x in columns\]))
df_final = df_spike.select('fresh')
df_final.write.txt(locatiion)
```

After writing this data in text format, when I am trying to read the data in XML, it is not reflecting all the rows.

**Method 2 - I followed:**

I read the data as text file and collected the element of the column one by one and removed the column one by one.

```py
list_data = \[\]
for i in range(df_spike.count()):
    df_collect = df_spike.collect()\[i\]\[0\]
    df_list_data = df_collect\[12:\]
    list_data.append(df_list_data)
```

This method is working fine; but it is taking excessive time as it is traversing through one by one row of the data.

Is there any efficient method to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please show the sample data or the result

Comment: As I am not able to take the data out of my work environment , So it will not be possible to show the data.